# I am using below code to run the code, It shows pop up to allow the camera Now i am getting below error

Tags: python, opencv

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)

while True:

success, img = cap.read()
cv2.imshow("Face Attandance", img)
cv2.waitkey(1)
```

That is the error:

> OpenCV: out device of bound (0-0): 1
>
> OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize! Traceback (most recent
> call last): File
> "/Users/virendradekate/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line
> 9, in <module> cv2.imshow("Face Attandance", img) cv2.error:
> OpenCV(4.5.4-dev)
> /private/var/folders/b7/g6qfbypj0tq32j5_trjh516r0000gn/T/pip-req-build-yhobjvo0/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1006:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in
> function 'imshow'